# For Excel's CHOOOSE() function, is there a shortcut to list multiple values?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel tells me that, for the CHOOSE() function, I should list between 1 and 254 values. Is there a quick way to enter these values into the function, or does each value need to be entered manually? In my case, I want the values to be cell references from a row vector e.g. B1, B2, B3, ..., B100 (with the index being a reference to, say, cell A1).

**Example**
Cell A1 contains a number from 1 to 254.

Cells B1 to B254 contain numbers.

I want Excel to use the index in A1 (i.e. a number from 1 to 254) to choose the corresponding number from cells B1 to B254. For example, if the number in cell A1 was 231, I want Excel to choose the number contained in cell B231.

When I write the choose function, do I have to write =CHOOSE(A1, B1, B2, B3, and then manually enter the remaining references up to B254) or is there a shortcut to entering all 254 values?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why would you use `CHOOSE` in such a scenario and not simply `INDEX`?

Comment: Ah I had not known about INDEX. Much better. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("B"&A1)
```

[image]

Comment: I had not thought to use INDIRECT. Much better. Thanks

Comment: I would never recommend to use a volatile function such as INDIRECT when a non-volatile one will do the job very easily, such as using INDEX in this case.